# HTTP POST fails when view has default name (route config)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The post of a view fails. It seems like the action name is missed.

[image]

If I change the POST action name in both controller and view to another arbitrary name, it works.

Controller

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Authentication
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new IndexViewModel();

        return View(model);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Default");
            }
            else
            {
                model.ErrorMessage = "Failed to login. Please try again!";
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model Test.Web.Models.Authentication.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log In";
}

<h2>Enter credentials to log on</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Authentication"))
{
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Username)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password)
</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
}
```

I'm pretty sure the reason is the RouteConfig and the default action name.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

One solution is of course to rename both the GET and POST action, and not use Index, but is there a way of getting this to work as it is? Without any hack, that is.

Comment: Is there no way you could define the routes above the methods?

Comment: Not sure. I'm able to workaround this if I choose another name than Index for my method/view, so no big issue. Still, it is always nice to know if there is another approach

Comment: Try adding [Route("//The path to the method")] above the controller method

Comment: Tried both [Route("~/Authentication/Index")] and [Route("Authentication/Index")], with no luck

Comment: Could you tell me what happens when you get the error? Where does it go? Is it possible that it is going to another controller?

Comment: I get a HTTP 405 as it tries to go to ../Authentication   with no action specified

Comment: Is there any reason in particular that there needs to be a GET above the Index?

Comment: No. It doesn't change anything by removing it though

Comment: I think you need to enable attribute routing in your route config to specify routes on the methods. I can see from your post that you are showing a POST request but as you have not specified a method on BeginForm is it rendering out a GET request? `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Authentication", FormMethod.POST)`

Comment: Craig H, I've also tried with the FormMethod.Post in the Html.BeginForm. The result is the same.